# Read multiple inputs and store in a array, then print the values from that array in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Read multiple inputs then store that in an array or variables, then print the values from that array/variables in shell script

```
read -p " Enter no. of users : " no_user
            if [ $no_user -gt 1 ]; then
                for ((i=1;; i++)); do
                    read -p "Enter Mob no ($i) : " $[mob$i]
                    if [ $i == $no_user ]; then break; fi
                done
            else
                read -p "Enter Mob no ($i) : " mob$i
            fi
                if [ $no_user > 1 ]; then
                    for ((i=1;; i++)); do
                        echo "Mobile no $i = " $[mob$i]
                            if [ $i == $no_user ]; then break; fi
                    done
                fi
```

Comment: You forgot the question.

Comment: I think the answer is 42.

Comment: Using a loop that just reads users until a sentinel/blank line is read instead of asking for a count is probably a friendlier model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$[mob$i]` and `mob$i` to `mob[$i]` at line **5** and **9**. And also change `$[mob$i]` to `${mob[$i]}` at line **13**

Complete code:

```
read -p " Enter no. of users : " no_user
if [ $no_user -gt 1 ]; then
for ((i=1;; i++)); do
read -p "Enter Mob no ($i) : " mob[$i]
if [ $i == $no_user ]; then break; fi
done
else
read -p "Enter Mob no ($i) : " mob[$i]
fi
if [ $no_user > 1 ]; then
for ((i=1;; i++)); do
echo "Mobile no $i = " ${mob[$i]}
if [ $i == $no_user ]; then break; fi
done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mob$i` instead of `$[mob$i]` on line 4 will fix your problem.